# How to handle QComboBox wheel-events with an event-filter?

Tags: python, events, mousewheel, pyside6, qcombobox

In Qt6, many widgets (QComboBox, QSpinBox) will steal mouse wheel events that should be handled by their parent widget (like a QScrollArea), even when they don't have focus, and even when the `focusPolicy` has been set to `StrongFocus`.

I can subclass these widget classes and re-implement the `wheelEvent` handler to ignore these events to accomplish what I want, but it feels inelegant to do it this way because I need to subclass every widget class that exhibits this behavior.

```py
class MyComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QtGui.QWheelEvent) -> None:
        if not self.hasFocus():
            event.ignore()
        else:
            super().wheelEvent(event)
```

Qt offers another way to ignore events using `installEventFilter`, which feels much more scalable and elegant, because I can create one Event Filter and apply it to any number of different widgets.

```py
class WheelEventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    """Ignores wheel events when a widget does not already have focus."""

    def eventFilter(self, watched: QtCore.QObject, event: QtCore.QEvent) -> bool:
        if (
            isinstance(watched, QtWidgets.QWidget)
            and not watched.hasFocus()
            and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.Wheel
        ):
            # This filters the event, but it also stops the event 
            # from propagating up to parent widget.
            return True
            # This doesn't actually ignore the event for the given widget.
            event.ignore()
            return False

        else:
            return super().eventFilter(watched, event)
```

My problem, though, is that this event filter doesn't seem to be filtering the events as I would expect. I expect it to filter out the event **for the `watched` object only**, while also allowing the event to be propogated up to the parent widget to handle, but that isn't happening.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect as the `wheelEvent` handler defined above using an `eventFilter`?

---

Here is a self-contained reproducible example that displays this behavior. If you try and scroll the scroll area with the mouse over one of the comboboxes, the combobox will steal focus and the wheel event.

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # # layout
        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

        # layout for widget
        self._mainwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self._mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._mainwidget.setLayout(self._mainlayout)

        # widgets for widget
        self._widgets = {}
        num_widgets = 20
        for i in range(num_widgets):
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems([str(x) for x in range(1, 11)])
            combo.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.FocusPolicy.StrongFocus)
            self._mainlayout.addWidget(combo)
            self._widgets[i] = combo

        # scroll area
        self._scrollarea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self._scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self._scrollarea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self._scrollarea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._scrollarea)

        # widget for scroll area
        self._scrollarea.setWidget(self._mainwidget)


def main() -> None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Setting the focus-policy to something less than [WheelFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum) should work, but it's hard to be certain without seeing a proper [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro I have set it to Strong Focus, and that prevents the widgets from gaining focus from wheel events, but they still eat the wheel event, so that if you are scrolling in a QScrollArea and the mouse is over one of these widgets, the scroll area stops scrolling.

Comment: You asked whether it was possible to achieve the same effect using an event-filter, and setting an appropriate focus-policy should allow that.

Comment: If you return `False`, the event will still be sent to the "watched" widget. If returning `True` doesn't cause the area to scroll, then you're doing something else wrong, so please provide a complete MRE as requested above.

Comment: @ekhumoro See posted example.

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. It doesn't have an event filter. I suspect you didn't do a preliminary debugging throughly. Did you print a log at your event filter? How did you install the filter?

Comment: @BrendanAbel As I pointed out above, the event-filter is obviously needed as well (which just needs to return true). This works perfectly well with Qt5, but it seems the same code does not work with Qt6. That may due to a bug in Qt6, or perhaps just a change in behaviour - I don't have time to investigate any further at the moment.

Comment: @ekhumoro, FYI, an event filter for disabling wheel events for a combo box works fine in both Qt5 and Qt6. Maybe you didn't install the filter to the ```QApplication``` instance.

Comment: @relent95 It certainly isn't necessary to install the event-filter on QApplication (it would be a bug if that were the case). As I suspected, there has been a slight change in behaviour between Qt5 and Qt6, which is easily dealt with.

Comment: @ekhumoro, it seems you meant installing an event filter on each combobox widget. I meant installing single filter to the application instance only once. In this case, you don't need to call ```event.ignore()``` for all Qt versions. The OP seems to not want a per instance solution.

Comment: @relent95 It appears `event.ignore()` is necessary in Qt6. In general, focus and events seem bugged in Qt6, or at least, the settings and behavior for some widgets have poor defaults for general use. I agree that this all works fine in Qt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found a solution that works with both Qt5 and Qt6.

It seems that in Qt6, it's necessary to explicitly ignore the wheel-event before returning true in the event-filter, whereas in Qt5 it's not. But note that I only tested this with Qt-5.15.11 and Qt-6.6.0 / Qt-6.2.2 on arch-linux, so I cannot guarantee this will work with all possible Qt versions and/or platforms. [It's also worth pointing out here that the current focus-policy behaviour of QComboBox (and other similar widgets) is somewhat questionable, because even when the focus-policy is set to `NoFocus`, the widget ***still*** accepts wheel-scroll events - see [QTBUG-19730](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19730). Really, reimplementing wheel-event handling is a somewhat crude work-around that shouldn't be necessary].

Below is a simplified working demo based on the code in the question. I have assumed the desired behaviour is that wheel-scrolling over an *unfocused* combo-box should still scroll the parent scroll-area, but a *focused* combo-box should scroll through its items as normal:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
        self._mainwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self._mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._mainwidget.setLayout(self._mainlayout)

        for i in range(20):
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(list('ABCDEF'))
            combo.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.FocusPolicy.StrongFocus)
            combo.installEventFilter(self)
            self._mainlayout.addWidget(combo)

        self._scrollarea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self._scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._scrollarea)
        self._scrollarea.setWidget(self._mainwidget)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.Wheel and
            not watched.hasFocus()):
            event.ignore()
            return True
        else:
            return super().eventFilter(watched, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()

    print(f'{QtCore.__package__} (Qt-{QtCore.qVersion()})')

    if hasattr(app, 'exec'):
        app.exec()
    else:
        app.exec_()
```